# How to download password protect files using the Gmail API in Python

Tags: python, encryption, gmail-api

I am trying to download password-protected attachments using the Gmail API in Python, however I can't see the files at all.

Below is using the ezgmail module:

```
    threads = ezgmail.search('LABEL:'+bank)
    for thread in threads:
        for message in thread.messages:
            print(message)
            for attachment in thread.message.attachments:
                print(attachment)
```

This loops through all the mails in all the threads with the specified label, and returns all of the attachments in those mails.
This works for normal files, but cases where the attachments are password-protect pdfs and Excel documents, I don't get anything back.

I also tried using the Gmail API directly with the same result:

```
for message in messages:    
        msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
        payload = msg['payload']
        parts = payload.get("parts")
        for part in parts:
            try:
                if part['filename']:
                    print("part[filename]")
                    if 'data' in part['body']:
                        data = part['body']['data']
                    else:
                        print(part['body'])
                        att_id = part['body']['attachmentId']
                        print(att_id)
```

Again, filename doesn't exist in Part.

Comment: I guess that's because gmail confidential email are prevented from being downloaded forwarded, copied or printed by recipients of the email according to google support ```https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7674059?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en```

Comment: @Khaled thanks for the response. I don't think that's the reason as I tried sending a mail to myself from an external address both in confidential mode and without confidential mode and was able to see the attachment in both emails, HOWEVER in testing that I realized that if I forward the problematic emails from before to myself then I can see those attachments. So the issue is either with the way that the sender is sending the message or with the fact that it's being sent to a group that I'm part of. Not with the fact that the email is encrypted.